# Access Android spell check lists

Tags: android

I would like to access the word lists used on android phones for spell checking (not including the user-defined-dictionary).

I am writing an app which i would like to be able to check if a word exists in the current phone users language. I imagine their is some API call or service i can use to access the build in word lists?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i know, each IME has its own dictionary and they probably implement their own method of reading from it. I have multiple keyboards installed on my phone, and if I add a word to the standard android keyboard, it still shows up as a miss-spelling if I switch to another keyboard.

Comment: ah really, ok thanks, good to know. What is an IME, input implementation?